# Angular project with 2 base-href configurations

Tags: angular, angular6, ionic4

Angular CLI: 7.2.3
Node: 10.14.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.2.2

My current index.html has base href set to `<base href="/" />` and my app runs at `http://localhost:port/`

Is it possible to have my app run at both `http://localhost:port/`and `http://localhost:port/something/` both on local and production build w/o having to set --base-href flag while building or `ng serve` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ng build --prod --base-href any value
i.e ng build --prod --base-href ./
```

Comment: Thank You @Zoha, However I need both / and /something base href in the same build